# why are the three targets for each slit in different columns

Tags: matrices

there are two slits and 3 targets possible to hit on the other sides so 5 of them in total, the matrix i was reading that describes it is this one in the figure,

$$\pmatrix{
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1/2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1/2&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1/3&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1/3&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&1/3&1/3&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1/3&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1/3&0&0&0&0&1}$$

[image]

i dont a hundred percent get the point of all the columns, the matrix is after one time click, the fractions are the chance the object will go to the left vertex or right slit vertex, to the target vertices, and from the targets to themselves, and 0 is at the top row because the object has a hundred percent chance to leave the first vertex. the targets have 1 chance because they stop there.

The matrix is after one click of time but to reach the targets only 2 clicks of time are necessary, and there is another matrix for the positions of the objects in the 2 slit experiment after 2 clicks of time, in the first matrix that i gave in the figure, why are there so many columns? there is one column for the distance to the slits, there are two columns for the distance from the slits to the targets, then there are 5 more columns with 1s in them i dont get what they are for and i dont get why the 3 targets for each slit are in different columns.

Comment: I have transformed your drawing into a "readable" version. Please check it.

Comment: For a non native english speaker like me : please explain what is a "slit" and a target  in this context ?

Comment: Why don't you answer my simple question ?

Comment: In fact for a native English speaker like me, pleasx explain in full detail what the heck you are talking about. Pretend that we cannot see inside your head, so the only things we can understand are those that you properly describe to us.